# Augmented matrix with multiple augmented columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to code a matrix solution solver that works for all matrices.
So my method is to row reduce all matrices to their reduced row echelon forms and then classify them according to their rank and number of free variables.

But I am confused about situations when a matrix has more than one augmented column. Yes, we can row reduce them to RREF but I don't know how to express the solution sets since I have only been dealing with one augmented column.

With one augmented column, we treat the column as a vector. But with more than one augmented column, we treat them as a matrix, but that's a linear transformation and that's not what I wanted. I want to view the augmented part in relation to the solution set.

I am new to linear algebra, so simple terminology and an example is much appreciated!

Comment: Why can’t you simply ignore all but one of the “extra” columns at a time? Why is the matrix augmented with multiple columns in the first place? (There are reasons to do this.)

Comment: It's not at all clear what kind of problem you want your solver to solve. If it's just $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a known matrix and $b$ is a known vector, then multiple augmented columns never show up. Are you hoping to solve $Ax=B$ where $A,B$ are both known matrices?

Comment: I intended to solve just Ax = b. But it would be nice to also solve Ax = B. Is there a known algorithm for solving this? Is the algorithm similar to solving Ax = b?

Comment: Pretty much identical, Gaussian elimination. Have you never used it to find the inverse of a square matrix?

Comment: I did. So to find x such that find Ax = B, I need to do (B-1A)x = identity matrix?

Comment: My goal is to express the solution set of Ax=B as a span of vectors just like Ax=b, if that's possible.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, Fin, you have to include @Gerry in it. When you write B-1, I think you mean $B^{-1}$, but $B$ might not have an inverse, it might not even be a square matrix. Now suppose you're given square matrices $A,B$ and you want to solve $AX=B$ (where $X$ will be a matrix). If $B$ is invertible then you can rewrite this as $(B^{-1}A)X=I$, etc., but first you'd have to find $B^{-1}$. Makes more sense to find $A^{-1}$, and then just use $X=A^{-1}B$.

Comment: Of course, the solution set of $AX=B$ will be a span of matrices, not vectors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! I think I get it now. Also, would augmented matrix addition, augmented matrix-vector multiplication, and two augmented matrices multiplication make sense?

Comment: Maybe you could post that as a new question.